# OpenCV - Earth Mover's Distance issue, icvInitEMD()

Tags: macos, algorithm, opencv

I am having trouble calling `EMD()` in OpenCV 2.4.2 under Mac OS ML.

I have a class with an attribute `Mat _signature` defined like that :

```
Mat _signature(size,dim+1,CV_32F);
for (int i = 0; i<size; ++i){
    _signature.at<float>(i,0) = weight;
    for (int j = 1; j < dim+1; ++j){
       _signature.at<float>(i,j) = vec[i].at<float>(0,j-1); // vec[i] is a line vector containing the position in R^dim
    }
}
```

I then have `u` and `v` 2 instances of that class, and when I call `EMD(u._signature, v._signature, CV_DIST_L2);`

It fails with `OpenCV Error: One of arguments' values is out of range () in icvInitEMD, file /*SOME PATH*/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/imgproc/src/emd.cpp, line 408`

I looked at the sourcecode but could not figure out what this fails. My arguments appear in correspondence to what the documentation wants. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure each member _signature is properly allocated/set when you call emd?

Comment: Yes, I checked that before and double checked just now. The `_signature` is correct and is `size*(dim+1)` as it should.

Comment: hard to tell what the problem is, I guess you can compile OpenCV in Debug and step into the problem using a debugger...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, it took me quite some time to figure it out, but among my data there was a component of one of my vector which was miscalculated, and ended up being `NaN`. 
Of course this was buried deep into my data so that it would be completely lost in any amount of data reasonably observable via a debugger (or even `cout`)

The cryptic error from OpenCV did the rest in confusing me.

For people stumbling upon the same issue as me :

- Make sure your weight vectors are not zero
- Make sure none of your data is `NaN`